# How can I fix my code so that it redirects the page according to the id of the submission in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to make a simple blog app using NodeJS, MongoDB and Express. My goal here is to be able to have the user write a title and text, have it go to my MongoDB database and have it show in a new, redirected page according to the ID of the new submission. However this is not working, the page will redirect and show "Cannot GET /users/postpage/(ID here)"

Here are my file paths:

```
config -->
    |auth.js
    |keys.js
    |passport.js
models -->
    |Createpost.js
    |User.js
routes -->
    |index.js
    |users.js
views -->
    dashboard.ejs
    postpage.ejs
app.js
```

My code in Createpost.js:

```
const TextSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    postTitle: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    postText: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

const Createpost = mongoose.model('Createpost', TextSchema);
```

My code in users.js:

```
router.get('postpage/:/id', (req,res)=>{
    res.send(req.params.id)
})

router.post('/postpage', async (req,res)=> {
    let newPost = new Createpost({
        postTitle:req.body.postTitle,
        postText:req.body.postText
    })

    try {
        newPost = await newPost.save()
        res.redirect(`/users/postpage/${newPost.id}`)
    } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
        res.render('users/postpage', {newPost:newPost})
    }

})
```

My code in postpage.ejs:

```
<form action="/users/postpage" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="postTitle">Title</label>
      <input required
        type="postTitle"
        id="postTitle"
        name="postTitle"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter title"
        value="<%= typeof postTitle != 'undefined' ? postTitle : '' %>"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="postText">text</label>
      <input required
        type="postText"
        id="postText"
        name="postText"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter text"
        value="<%= typeof postText != 'undefined' ? postText : '' %>"
      />
    </div>
```

Comment: This is not right, maybe just a typo `router.get('postpage/:/id',....` --> `postpage/:/id` should be `/postpage/:id`

Comment: Oh my god i feel so stupid, thank you so much